# Activity is killing when Login to Facebook from Android using Facebook sdk 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

Sometimes My Activity is killing when trying to Login with Facebook. When this happens I am unable to Login with facebook even I successfully LoggedIn from the Facebook App.

I also tried to call the Facebook login procedure from oncreate by checking savedinstancestate != null also. But here it is saying that Session is Opening so you can't Login .

Comment: post your log when it is killing .Have u check access token you are getting or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't check that but I am getting Session as not null with Session state is 'Opening'. So when Session state is Opening I am unable to Login or Share something to Facebook.

Comment: Also check you access token and post your log without it is not easy to determine the main issue

Comment: OK sure I will check and post the log.

Comment: No Actually that issue is coming 2 times out of 10 times so I am unable to get that issue again whenever I get that issue I will post the Log. But in my view if we get acesstoken also we can't do any operation with Facebook because of Session state is Opening.